# Symfony 4 Doctrine reverse engineering issues

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am trying to use doctrine to generate entities in symfony 4 from mysql database.

Firstly, I created a bundle called AppBundle.php in a directory called AppBundle

I then generate the xml of the schema using:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

This will create a folder called Resources in the AppBundle folder and then another folder called config and doctrine and all the orm.xml files are put in there.

Then I try to generate the entities using:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src/Entity
```

This creates the following folders in the Entity folder:

- Entity

  - App
  - AppBundle

    - Entity

And all the .php entity files are put in the second Entity folder.

[image]

The .php entity files have the following namespace

```
namespace App\AppBundle\Entity;
```

In my controller I added the name space

```
use App\AppBundle\Entity\User;
```

and use doctrine to fetch

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findAll();
```

but when I run the application I get this error

[image]

Now, when I move the second Entity folder into the AppBundle folder. The application works.

[image]

Is there a way to generate entities without Symfony generating the App folder or the AppBundle folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. AppBundle is deprecated way in Symfony 4. Recommended one is put all your code in \App namespace (`\App\Entity\User`). It's default behavior for all Symfony generators now.
2. If you want use a bundle you should:

2.1. configure doctrine like

   `orm:
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
                is_bundle: true
                type: xml
                prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'`

2.2. use `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src`

Also you should properly configure composer autoload and Symfony configs.

Comment: "Recommended one is put all your code in \App namespace". Do you mean this way? php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force \App xml